# What is the difference between these two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

It is hard for me to understand what the exact difference is between the [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) and [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) tags. What are the differences between these two tags?

Comment: Despite what the tag wiki says, some of the [tag:application] questions are about job applications. It seems like a confused tag.

Comment: @StrongBad It is confusing indeed. May we can have it renamed to *job-applications*. Then we have *job-applications* tags for questions about academic jobs and *graduate-admissions* for questions about applying to masters and PhD levels.

Comment: We already have [tag:faculty-application] and [tag:job-search]. I think it is just a case of cleaning them up.

Comment: @StrongBad Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) as being about the package of documents you submit in order to be considered for a job or for admissions. Whereas [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) is about the admissions process in general. (This is based on my observations of how the tags have been used so far, it doesn't say anything about this in the tag wikis or excerpts.)

For example, I consider the following to be in [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) but not necessarily [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application)

- [How does a prospective applicant fail to qualify for RAship, but fit the bill for TAship?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/how-does-a-prospective-applicant-fail-to-qualify-for-raship-but-fit-the-bill-fo)
- [Weaker chance of admit if classmate has already been admitted to graduate program?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38715/weaker-chance-of-admit-if-classmate-has-already-been-admitted-to-graduate-progra)

whereas the following are explicitly about the application that you submit for consideration

- [Is there a standard medical fitness certificate format for applicants to European universities?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36710/is-there-a-standard-medical-fitness-certificate-format-for-applicants-to-europea)
- [Is it acceptable to list unpublished papers in a PhD application for computer science?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38770/is-it-acceptable-to-list-unpublished-papers-in-a-phd-application-for-computer-sc)

Along the same lines, in [job-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search) there are some questions that *aren't* about the actual application, and some that are.

It's a subtle distinction, which is probably why it's not applied very consistently. But I do see this difference in their usage at least some of the time, so I don't believe these tags are redundant.

(I also *do* find these tags to be reasonably useful in their current state, i.e. even though they are not applied perfectly. So I would use the distinction above to tag new questions, but would not be in favor of re-tagging old questions en masse.)